# $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false) not working on IOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a slide box and in my controller I placed this to prevent the slide box labels from sliding left and right :

```
  $timeout(function() {
    return $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
  }, 1);
```

it works on Android, but not on IOS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one sliding controller left or right images.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('image-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.openModal = function(galryPubId) {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(galryPubId);
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hide', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  $scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
    console.log('Modal is shown!');
  });

  // Call this functions if you need to manually control the slides
  $scope.next = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
  };

  $scope.previous = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
  };

  $scope.goToSlide = function(index) {
    $scope.modal.show();
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
  }

  // Called each time the slide changes
  $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
    $scope.slideIndex = index;
  };
```

It's work for both the platform Android / iOS.